# AuthComponent deos not work in pages controller?

Tags: cakephp

I have set up ACL successfully, but the problem is that when I want to go to the homepage it redirects me to the login page. I tried this in my `pagescontroller`:

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
```

It did not work. Then I allowed the display action in app controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array(
      'controller' => 'pages',
      'action' => 'display', 'homepage'
    ));}
```

but still it is redirecting me to the login page, whereas in my user controller when allowed access to some actions, it worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: if you set up ACL successfully.. did you grant your method to the user role?

Comment: Problem Solved. Actually, I included different elements with requestActions in my hompepage.ctp. So other controller were being called in my homepage whereas their access was denied by ACL. I just removed the Elements and it worked.